# Is possible multiples GPUs work as one with more memory?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker, bert-language-model

I have a deep learning workstation where there are 4 GPUs with 6 GB of memory each. Would it be possible to make a docker container see the 4 GPUs as one but with 24 GB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Alternate answer: Yes, but requires additional hardware, expensive, and probably incompatible with your existing hardware.

Explanation:

It is possible if your GPUs are connected using `NVIDIA NVLink` (take a look at the details here https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/nvlink-bridges/).

Usually `NVLink` used for pairs of GPUs, like GPU0 connected with GPU1 and GPU2 connected with GPU3, in this case best option you can obtain is 2 GPUs with doubled memory each.

Another option is special `InfiniBand` module, installed to modern GPU servers by some vendors.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't work with docker before but work a lot with CUDA with Multiple GPU. Since multiple GPUs is physically are separated, hence working with multiple GPUs required a lot of memory synchronization in code level.

I don't think that docker can virtually merge all the GPU memory as that will make the computation very complicated on the GPU side. working with Multiple GPU required custom kernel to synchronize to each other.

The best analogy I relate is, "Can you get two bare-metal computers to merge the RAM and run Microsoft Word as if it were a single machine?".